# What is the best approach to store audit-log / change-history in dynamodb?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, audit-logging

The purpose is to build a `Audit Log` service to store change history for an application. The following information will be stored:

```
 - srcId
 - srcTable
 - changedAt
 - changes
 - user
```

For example, for the username change of id = 10 from profile table will be saved like

```
srcId = 10,
srcTable = 'profile',
changedAt = timestamp,
changes: { name: { old: old-value, new: new-value } },
user: the-user-id-who-performed-the-change-action
```

Trying to build the system based on `aws lambda`, `dynamodb`.

Initially thought to use `srcId` as sort-key, `srcTable` as partition key. But as there can be multiple entries for same `srcId/srcTable` pair, where the `changedAt` will be different. Any suggestion on how the index or primary key should be set for better performance gain.

P.S. expected queries

- most of the query will be to obtain change list for `srcId/srcTable` pair [ ~90% ]
- finding change history for `srcTable` [ 5% ~ 7% ]
- finding changes made by user [ 3% ~ 5% ]

(percentage values are roughly perceived about the expected behaviour)

Comment: What’s the cardinality of srcId and srcTable?  And do you have approx anticipated record volumes ?

Comment: @fedonev there is no approx as the change-history is expected to grow with time.

Comment: As the [docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach), "it is important to understand three fundamental properties of your application's access patterns before you begin: Data size, Data shape, Data velocity".   In other words, "best" key selection depends on your data's cardinality and record/query volumes (100 or 1k or 1m, 10m new daily records?  10, 1k, 1m, 10m queries per day?).

Answer (score 1):

It would be best that your Table PK have [a high cardinality](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/). Based on your examples, you could achieve that by creating a computed column on the `srcTable:srcId` combination (I prefer using `:` instead of `#`) and then use your timestamp as your sort key.

This achieves the primary query pattern which is to find the change list for a given `srcTable` and `srcId`. Using the timestamp will allow you to query the table based on date ranges which in my experience is a common use case for audit logs.

Table (Get change history for `<srcTable>:<srcId>`):

- PK - `srcTable:srcId`
- SK - `changedAt`

GSI1 (Get change history for `<srcTable>`):

- PK - `srcTable`
- SK - `changedAt`

GSI2 (Get changes performed by `<user>`):

- PK - `user`
- SK - `changedAt`

Your items may look similar to this:

| PK (`srcTable`:`srcId`) | SK (`<changedAt>`) | `srcTable` | `srcId` | `userId` | `changes` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| profile:10 | 2021-11-25T06:02:27.163Z | profile | 10 | 1 | {} |
| user:1 | 2021-11-25T06:03:09.811Z | user | 1 | 1 | {} |
| profile:12 | 2021-11-25T06:04:17.178Z | profile | 12 | 4 | {} |

You might have looked at this already but for the sake of future readers, I would highly suggest watching or following [Rick Houlihan's videos on Advanced DynamoDB modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k). Another great resource is [Alex DeBrie's DynamoDB Book](https://www.dynamodbbook.com/).

Comment: So when there are multiple updates on `profile:10` on different time, won't there be same PK with different SK? Thus it won't insert new item instead will update the old one with.

Comment: The Table PK-SK combination determines the unique constraint for a DynamoDB table. So if you have updates on `profile:10` on different times, they will be created as multiple items. If you update them fast enough that there might be updates in the same millisecond, you can increase the precision to microseconds or add a random suffix.